# jQuery UI resizable pinch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, touch, pinch

Is it possible to add touch pinch support to jQuery UI's `resizable`? So on an iPad, you wouldn't need to use the specified handles to resize, but you could just use two fingers and pinch on the element to resize.

Comment: Please have a look at [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) its a js library for multi-touch gestures, so that should help :) And yes it will work on IOS.

Answer (score 1):

**[jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)** is exactly what you're looking for. It adds touch event support for jQuery UI and is tested on a variety of platforms including iPad, iPhone, Android and other touch-enabled mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I would check for another library that does this already. In theory, you *could* extend jQuery UI or add on additional events to the elements with jQuery. If you decided to delve into that madness I'd suggest adding on your own events with a library like Touchy:

http://touchyjs.org/